# using if statement in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to use if statement in sql query :

what I want :

```
if(tractions_delivery.send_date_id !=0 ){

           date_send_commodities.id  = tractions_delivery.send_date_id
}
```

---

my query :

```
        from

            tractions_delivery,user_address,province,city,date_send_commodities,users

        WHERE

        tractions_delivery.tr_id = $tr_id
        AND
        tractions_delivery.address_id = user_address.id
        AND
        user_address.province_id = province.id
        AND
        user_address.city_id      = city.id
        AND
        //not work
        (tractions_delivery.send_date_id IS NOT 0 date_send_commodities.id  = tractions_delivery.send_date_id)

        AND
        users.id = user_address.user_id
```

Comment: Can you clarify what this query is supposed to do please?

Comment: ...
AND CASE WHEN tractions_delivery.send_date_id != 0 THEN date_send_commodities.id  = tractions_delivery.send_date_id ELSE 1=1 END AND
        users.id = user_address.user_id

Comment: What is `IS NOT 0`? You can write `IS NOT NULL` or `<> 0`.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian :Try this: IF(tractions_delivery.send_date_id <> 0, date_send_commodities.id, <some_other_column>) = tractions_delivery.send_date_id

Comment: @iiro your answer is true and work fine.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian ok thanks! I'll write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the CASE-statement

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
 tractions_delivery,
 user_address,
 province,
 city,
 date_send_commodities,users
WHERE
 tractions_delivery.tr_id = $tr_id AND
 tractions_delivery.address_id = user_address.id AND
 user_address.province_id = province.id AND
 user_address.city_id = city.id AND
 CASE WHEN tractions_delivery.send_date_id != 0 THEN date_send_commodities.id = tractions_delivery.send_date_id ELSE 1=1 END AND
 users.id = user_address.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use if statements in stored procedures or functions. If you just write a sql statement unfortunately you cannot use if statements around the query. But you can use logic in the query itself, e.g.:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 = col2 THEN'col1 equals col2' else 'col1 doesnt equal col2' ELSE
FROM table1
```

So around doesnt work, but in the field list you can create CASE WHEN ELSE END logic.

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` or `IF()` operators can be of help.

Examples,

```
SELECT (CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN 'One' WHEN 2 THEN 'Two' ELSE 'More' END) 'Result';
```

OR

```
SELECT IF(1=1, 'One', 'Two') 'Result';
```

These `CASE` and `IF()` operators can be used in the `SELECT` clause to conditionally interpret column values and return in the resultset.

Note: Do not confuse `CASE` operator here with '`CASE` conditional syntax block' that ends with `END CASE`.